# Could the latin word terrere be related to the Hebrew word תִּירָא (tira)?

Tags: etymology, latin, hebrew

The English word "terror" is derived from the Latin "terrere", meaning "frighten". I noticed in reading a passage in Isaiah the Hebrew equivalent of "don't be afraid" which is אַל־תִּירָא ('al tira' - the ' is a mild glottal stop) where "be afraid" is "tira'" and "don't" is "'al". The form of the verb here is the second person (Qal) imperfect. The infinitive is יָרֵא (yare'). It's a stretch, but is there a chance that the Latin word could have roots in the Hebrew?

Comment: I turned out to be what's known as a chance resemblance.

Comment: Which should be the default assumption for similar words between unrelated languages.

Comment: Why this question was downvoted?

Answer (score 6):

Almost certainly not. Latin *terreō* "frighten" has cognates all across the Indo-European world (AGrk *tréō* "to be afraid", Sanskrit *trásati* "to tremble with fear", OCS *tręsti* "to shake", OIr *tarrach* "timid", etc). This is strong evidence that it descends from a Proto-Indo-European word for "fear".

Comment: There is an alternative theory that it relates to *TERS, meaning $dry$.  (Sudden fear causes a dry mouth.)

Comment: @BertBarrois Oh, interesting, hadn't heard that one before. So cognate with "terra" and "thirst" in that case?

Comment: I cannot recall where I saw this theory, and I don't believe it myself, but it isn't any wilder than the metaphoric connection among *gorse ~ horrēre ~ harṣayati*.

Comment: The same analogy can be drawn between *[scare](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scare)*, uncertain beyond Norse "shy, timid", to a similar root, \*(s)kel- "withered" cf *skeleton*; cp \*(s)ker- >  [shrink](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shrink); be sure to scroll down, they list two entries: a) "to cut", b) "to turn, coil"; scroll further for "see \*(s)skel-, \*(s)kelH-". Cp \*sker- without s-mobile? Cp *screw*, uncertain; cp G *aufschrecken* "to jump up, scared", *Schreck* "scare", *Schrecken* (idem); cp *Leid* "sorrow" vs *Leiden* < *leiden* "suffer"; *Leidenschaft*, *Passion*.